# SSRS: Add multiple if statements

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS to add certain values in a column together. If the Service ID is 13,15,18,or 19 I want it too add these values together. Right now I have:

```
=IIf(Fields!ServiceID.Value = 13,Fields!TermPrimary.Value, Nothing) + IIf(Fields!ServiceID.Value = 15,Fields!TermPrimary.Value, Nothing) + IIf(Fields!ServiceID.Value = 18,Fields!TermPrimary.Value, Nothing) + IIf(Fields!ServiceID.Value = 19,Fields!TermPrimary.Value, Nothing)
```

I thought This would allow me to add these values together, instead it only shows me the exact same values as the table below it showing serviceID 13. How do I add these figures together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Service ID** field will always be a single number and **never** equal to 13 **AND** 15 on the same line.

I think you want to **Group** your column by some other field and **SUM** the **TermPrimary** for that group IIF the **ServiceID** is one of your given values.

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!ServiceID.Value = 13 OR Fields!ServiceID.Value = 15 OR Fields!ServiceID.Value = 18 OR Fields!ServiceID.Value = 19, Fields!TermPrimary.Value, 0)
```

Comment: For the Most part, I have a field called month which Is grouped by month in the column, so my data is ServiceID=13.Month=Jan,Data=5, Then the Next row is, ServiceID=13.Month=Feb,Data=5. If the ServiceID equals one of the these numbers, 13,15,18,19. I want it too add up the Jan of all of those, the Feb of all of those and so forth. The Formula you posted errors out though.

Comment: So you are already grouping. I don't see why the **SUM** formula wouldn't work then. Do you have an error message? Check the Error List at the bottom. If **TermPrimary** isn't an **Integer**, you'd need to convert it (or the **0** to **CDBL**). You might also post a pic of the design view if you can't make it work.

Comment: Ahh nm, The Error was on me, I recopied and it worked, for future people this is indeed the answer to my question.